# PRXY0007: The request or the response message was incomplete or malformed. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: automation, coded-ui-tests

I am receiving following error message in the browser while running coded ui test in a remote VM using VSTS 2010 test Agent.

PRXY0007: The request or the response message was incomplete or malformed. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Can any one throw some info on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went in to my **Internet Options** and **Connections** tab.  And then under "**Lan Settings**"

Uncheck everything.

This seemed to fix it for me.